# Can ant design support multiple custom variants of a component?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

We started using ant design for our react project and I'm attempting to create multiple variants of a button. I'm used to native base in which I can create various custom variants for a button by modifying the theme config, but from what I can can tell ant design's config provider only allows me to override the base theme and not actually create various variants of a button. Is there a way inside of ant design that I can create multiple variants of a component so I don't have to override the css outside of ant design?

I've looked at their docs here but it doesn't seem like they support multiple variants: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, take a look in [this](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#local-theme) section of antd docs.

You'll maybe need to create a separated component so you can handle your own styles in many different ways.

Here's a simple example:

```
// app.tsx
import { Button as AntButton, ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import CustomButton from "./button";

function Index() {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        components: {
          Button: {
            colorPrimary: "#f00"
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      <AntButton type={"primary"}> Default button </AntButton>
      <CustomButton color={"#00f"} />
      <CustomButton color={"#0f0"} />
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}

// button.tsx

import { Button, ConfigProvider } from "antd";

type ComponentType = { color: string };
function Index({ color }: ComponentType) {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        components: {
          Button: {
            colorPrimary: color
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      <Button type={"primary"}>Custom button</Button>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-example-mn9kss?file=/button.tsx:0-394)'s a working codesandbox example.

Hope this helps